# Debian wifi hard blocked, working only after suspend

Tags: debian, wifi, thinkpad, iwlwifi

My system is the latest Debian stretch (9.4) on a ThinkPad L380 which has a Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 card. The special key for enabling/disabling wifi works but does not change the hard blocked condition.

`rfkill list all` yields the following

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

`rfkill unblock all` doesn't change anything.

`dmesg`:

```
[    2.872137] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    2.872139] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[    2.872486] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.876566] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode (-2)
[    2.876573] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.876585] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8265-25.ucode (-2)
[    2.876589] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.876598] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode (-2)
[    2.876602] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.876611] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8265-23.ucode (-2)
[    2.876615] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.878550] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    2.880064] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
[    2.880899] [drm] Finished loading i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    2.881548] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
[    2.882171] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.896266] kvm: disabled by bios
[    2.898967] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[    2.899261] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    2.900584] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    2.900586] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    2.900588] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    2.900590] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    2.903322] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.905080] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.910783] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    2.911257] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8
[    2.911369] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20160919 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    2.930964] ucsi_acpi: probe of USBC000:00 failed with error -110
[    2.931015] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input9
[    2.946639] i2c_hid i2c-INT3515:02: unexpected HID descriptor bcdVersion (0x0000)
[    2.969235] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.969634] thermal thermal_zone8: failed to read out thermal zone (-5)
[    2.973763] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    2.993050] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    3.097358] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.154598] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    3.154599] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    3.179329] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for Generic: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    3.179331] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.179334] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.179335] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.179337] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    3.179339] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    3.179341] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    3.191106] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
[    3.191189] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
[    3.191265] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
[    3.191343] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
[    3.191430] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[    3.274143] random: crng init done
[    3.373058] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.373058] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.373061] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.570603] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[    3.785160] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[    3.793653] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    4.418209] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    4.418301] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1686937 usecs
[    4.418426] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    4.430367] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11735 usecs
[    4.432598] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
[    4.432604] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
[    4.434334] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    4.434512] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    4.457449] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    4.817747] [drm] RC6 on
[  183.889440] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  183.889445] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  183.889450] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

`dmesg` after suspend:

```
[  365.379893] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[  365.382921] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[  365.383087] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
[  365.383332] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[  365.383362] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
[  365.383573] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
[  365.383620] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[  365.384944] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[  365.386059] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[  365.386098] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  365.518772] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
[  365.800524] PM: suspend of devices complete after 294.867 msecs
[  365.828976] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 28.444 msecs
[  365.837474] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  365.880923] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  365.916944] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 87.962 msecs
[  365.917688] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  366.020987] ACPI : EC: event blocked
[  366.020988] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
[  366.020989] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  366.021000] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  366.022735] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[  366.039307] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[  366.063297] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[  366.087841] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[  366.110934] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[  366.134904] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[  366.158874] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[  366.180266] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[  366.180375] ACPI : EC: EC started
[  366.180376] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[  366.181093] Suspended for 14.006 seconds
[  366.181149] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  366.192664] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[  366.192665] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[  366.195048]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[  366.195208] CPU1 is up
[  366.208592] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[  366.211383]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[  366.211679] CPU2 is up
[  366.224603] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[  366.227400]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[  366.227700] CPU3 is up
[  366.240619] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
[  366.243639]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
[  366.243981] CPU4 is up
[  366.256644] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
[  366.259517]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
[  366.259858] CPU5 is up
[  366.272656] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
[  366.275536]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
[  366.275897] CPU6 is up
[  366.288664] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
[  366.291540]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
[  366.292063] CPU7 is up
[  366.303628] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[  366.661536] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  366.661575] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 65.045 msecs
[  366.673068] PM: early resume of devices complete after 11.452 msecs
[  366.673178] ACPI : EC: event unblocked
[  366.673671] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  366.674032] ACPI : button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
[  366.674067] rtc_cmos 00:03: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  366.674076] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[  366.681335] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[  366.739793] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 6 resume PLC timeout
[  366.977498] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  367.297291] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  367.439880] PM: resume of devices complete after 766.807 msecs
[  367.440297] usb 1-7:1.0: rebind failed: -517
[  367.440301] usb 1-7:1.1: rebind failed: -517
[  367.440685] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[  367.440687] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  367.444167] thermal thermal_zone8: failed to read out thermal zone (-5)
[  367.446979] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[  367.447922] [drm] RC6 on
[  367.447954] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[  367.447955] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[  367.447956] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[  367.447957] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[  367.447958] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[  367.447959] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[  367.447962] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[  367.572753] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
[  367.573316] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[  367.788561] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[  367.789646] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  367.792250] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  367.793168] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  367.910290] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  367.910749] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  367.972456] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  367.984050] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  367.985447] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  368.103032] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  368.103417] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  368.162578] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  368.240193] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  368.956315] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[  368.957013] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1475934 usecs
[  368.957104] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[  368.968956] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11659 usecs
[  368.968960] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
[  368.971033] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[  371.590758] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  371.717298] wlp2s0: authenticate with 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9
[  371.728900] wlp2s0: send auth to 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9 (try 1/3)
[  371.733499] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  371.736554] wlp2s0: associate with 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9 (try 1/3)
[  371.740114] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  371.742706] wlp2s0: associated
[  371.763991] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  421.946525] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  421.971128] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  422.801433] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  423.825836] wlp2s0: authenticate with 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72
[  423.833627] wlp2s0: send auth to 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72 (try 1/3)
[  423.841483] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  423.844477] wlp2s0: associate with 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72 (try 1/3)
[  423.847587] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[  423.850208] wlp2s0: associated
[  423.859782] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  615.260094] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72 for new auth to 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9
[  615.267474] wlp2s0: authenticate with 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9
[  615.276197] wlp2s0: send auth to 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9 (try 1/3)
[  615.276915] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  615.283055] wlp2s0: associate with 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9 (try 1/3)
[  615.284028] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  615.284930] wlp2s0: associated
[  718.274056] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 50:c7:bf:f0:1a:f9 for new auth to 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72
[  718.285258] wlp2s0: authenticate with 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72
[  718.294788] wlp2s0: send auth to 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72 (try 1/3)
[  718.399207] wlp2s0: send auth to 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72 (try 2/3)
[  718.411186] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  718.415211] wlp2s0: associate with 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72 (try 1/3)
[  718.498645] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 50:c7:bf:72:0d:72 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[  718.507714] wlp2s0: associated
```

Another thing I noticed is that the special keys for adjusting display brightness show the same behaviour.

Comment: I would still try the special wifi-key - even if it doesn't "work" as under windows, I often had the impression it could block my wifi access.

Comment: Linux kernel is notorious for not working gracefully with network cards around sleep modes. File a bug report, but I would not hold my breath. The times when user bug reports got looked into are a thing of distant past (like 20 years ago).

Comment: @A.B I'm not quite sure how to load it. I tried setting THINKPAD_ACPI as well as SND and RFKILL from 'm' to 'y' but it did not change anything

Comment: It wasn't loaded, so my Fn-keys work now, thank you. However my wifi remains hard-blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading from debian stretch to the buster (testing) release fixed the issue for me.

Edit: If you don't want to upgrade to a testing distribution, there is also the option to install a newer kernel via [stretch-backports](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) instead. After updating my `/etc/apt/sources.list` accordingly, I installed the [newest available kernel](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/kernel/linux-image-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64) and wifi works upon boot now. It might also be necessary to install the [backports version of iwlwifi](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/kernel/firmware-iwlwifi).

In conclusion: the problem was due to an outdated kernel.

Comment: However, I did not get eduroam (WPA2 enterprise) to work with buster so I'm currently back to stretch again.